# "No such file or directory" but it's there. Shell script looping through array of folders

Tags: shell, ssh, directory

I'm trying to automate the download of a subdirectories in a directory. However, when executing the script, the last one or two directories cannot be found by the script - "No such file or directory". All others do fine and can be downloaded. This occurs for all directories I've tried this on which is strange to me. Why would it always not find the last two directories? 
Can anyone help with this? Is it due to the loop? I've tried changing it to loop over the last ones only and this doesn't help. Or maybe it's due to the conversion of `array=($l)`?

Here's my script:

```
dirServer=/dir/to/location/in/server
dirLocal=/dir/to/location/in/local/pc 

l=`ssh -t username@server 'ls' ${dirServer}`

#array of folders that should be copied to local machine
array=($l)


for folder in ${array[@]}
do
  echo ${folder}

  #if directory doesn't exist, creat it
  mkdir -p ${dirLocal}${folder}
  scp -r username@server:${dirServer}${folder}/analysis/ ${dirLocal}${folder}
done
```

Comment: Which command is producing the error message and what directory is it complaining about? Could you [edit] your question to include a sample of the list of files that this script operates on?

Comment: `scp`produces the error. The files the script operates on are folders.

Answer (score -1):

Try change the following line including this "-o LogLevel=QUIET"

```
l=`ssh -o LogLevel=QUIET -t username@server 'ls' ${dirServer}`
```

Explanation:

That is coming from SSH. You see it because you gave the -t switch, which forces SSH to allocate a pseudo-terminal for the connection. Traditionally, SSH displays that message to make it clear that you are no longer interacting with the shell on the remote host, which is normally only a question when SSH has a pseudo-terminal allocated.

Comment: I did a simulation and in my case the problem was generated by the return of ssh command. When ssh ends the message "Connection to <server> closed." is showed.

Can you put here a sample of your server folder structure?

I realized too that "/" is missing between ${dirServer} and ${folder}